# How can I install an npm module on a disconnected computer, ensuring all dependencies

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, offline

I need to work on a disconnected computer network (no internet access) and I was hoping to use jsbin for SharePoint/Windows development, which highly recommends npm for installation, to ensure all dependencies are there.

Is there a way to run npm on a connected computer, then copy one or more folders to the target network, and thus install the module(s) on a different computer that has NodeJS, either using npm or not(?)

I see references to [npm pack](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack), but I'm new enough with this (and come from a primarily Windows environment) that that doesn't quite make sense to me

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it with grunt-cli (another globally installed package).

```
# do this on connected computer
npm install -g jsbin
npm pack jsbin
# this will drop a jsbin-[version number].tgz in the cwd
# move this file to new computer and…

# do this on not-connected computer
npm install -g jsbin-[version number].tgz
```

Comment: Seems simple enough! Trying as soon as I can (anything brought over has to be checked first), thanks!

Comment: Still in the process - ugh. I did have some issues with the [latest version of node.js (v0.12.6)](https://nodejs.org/download/) and this particular package (jsbin's developer [only claims compatibility with node.js v0.10.x](https://github.com/jsbin/jsbin/issues/2370#issuecomment-108717567)), so I had to downgrade to v0.10.39 from [the archive of releases](https://nodejs.org/dist/)

Comment: I use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)  instead of re-installing node all the time for instances just like this.